# Worst number of flipping

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assuming that we want to perform the re-ordering 4,3,5,1,2 in 
≤ P5 steps, but we don’t know how to do this.

So, we decided to write a computer program to try all possible flips 
(brute force method) 
to determine the correct sequence of flips to achieve this target.

What is the worst number of flips that must be tried by our program?

Comment: What exactly constitutes a flip?

Comment: I imagine a flip means swapping two numbers in the sequence...?